# How to calculate the mean of a group in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataset with a range of ages. I'm trying to calculate the mean of the another variable happy. I'm trying to get the mean of happy at age 18,19,20... and so on and then plot it on a graph to see how the mean happy changes with age. I'm doing this in R. Any advice or recommendations would be much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: working this this code currently

EDIT: made by Infiniteflash, adjusted code.

```
GGage <- ggplot(aes(x = AGE, y= happynew), data = newgss)   + geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = mean , color = "red")
```

Comment: Show some code of what you have tried and what errors you are getting. If you haven't tried anything yet then this question is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
library(dplyr)

Mean_of_a_group <- dataset %>% group_by(age_group) %>% summarize(happy = mean(happy))
```

I suggest using ggplot2 to do what you want here.

```
ggplot(data = Mean_of_a_group, aes(age_group, happy))+ geom_point
```

**Dummy example**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = disp, y= mpg), data = mtcars)+

geom_smooth(aes(colour = "red"), data = mtcars, stat = "smooth", formula = y ~ x , se = FALSE)+

geom_smooth(aes(coluor = "blue"), data = mtcars, stat = "smooth", formula = y ~ poly(x,2), se = FALSE)+

geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I'm looking for. Follow up question. How do I add a trend line that allows for a curve on the ggplot? I want to show if happy is going up or down with age.

Comment: Also please revise the question, it has no details whatsoever. Usually questions like the OP get down voted a lot without any code for us to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm trying to add the regression line    lm(happy~ Age + Age^2)


I got this far :

    GGage <- ggplot(aes(x = AGE, y= happynew), data = newgss)   + geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = mean , color = "red")
GGage <- GGage + geomline(aes())

Comment: Okay hope it works it out.

For the record, if you want people to try our your code, please use `dput` in the future. I have no idea what some of those variables are.

Comment: I even added a nice example of what you want above.

Comment: Thanks a million. The code helps a lot